# Developer Console Debug Logs Viewer

Tags: developer-console, debug-logs

How can i see the entire body of the last debug log in developer console in Salesforce?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in normal log view (from spring 19). You need to open raw log or download it to view it fully. Right click on log to see options

[image]

Documentation:

> **Developer Console: String Values in Debug Logs Are Truncated**
>
> To help prevent connection pool timeouts caused by exceptionally large
>   queries, strings are now truncated at 512 characters in the Developer
>   Console’s Log Inspector. This truncation applies to all string values
>   in the Execution Log panel and to SOQL queries in the Source panel.
>   You can view the complete string in a raw log file. Where: This change
>   applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in Enterprise
>   Performance, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com editions.
>
> When: This change takes effect on March 6, 2019.
>
> How: To open a raw log, on the Logs tab, right-click a log and select
>   Open Raw Log. Or, to open your newest raw log, select File | Open Raw
>   Log. You can also access raw logs through the API by querying the
>   Tooling API object ApexLog.

Source: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_developer_console.htm

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas. I forgot about reading that here on stack exchange couple  months ago.